# Can a bring a flammable body mist (100ml) with me?

Tags: airports

It's a vanilla scented body mist from the body shop. It's 100ml but my only worry is that's it's flammable.

Comment: Not that perfume is also flammable and it is allowed on airplanes. Who are you flying with? From where?

Comment: Everything's flammable if you get it hot enough.

Comment: @AakashM: Really "flammable" means easily set on fire, and in US it mean flash point is less then 100F, which is not hot. For combustion it is necessary that the reaction is exothermic. Just hot enough is not enough.

Comment: Bring it with you where? Note that almost all aerosol sprays are flammable and it's rarely a problem.

Answer (score 4):

> Note: Nonflammable aerosols are rare.

I don't say that. [FAA](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ash/ash_programs/hazmat/media/Hazardous_Materials_Carried_by_Passengers_and_Crew.pdf) does

> **Allowed**
>
> Toiletry or medicinal articles that are hazardous materials such as rubbing alcohol, flammable perfume and colognes, nail polish and remover, and aerosols (hairspray, shaving cream, sunscreen, insect repellent, etc
>
> *Liquids, gels, and aerosols in carry-on baggage are further limited to 100-ml (3.4 ounce) containers by TSA security checkpoint rules.

[FAA](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ash/ash_programs/hazmat/media/Hazardous_Materials_Carried_by_Passengers_and_Crew.pdf) allows them at least. But that should generally be the case everywhere and without knowing the jurisdiction its hard to answer.